# How to set up Phoenix (elixir) with surrealdb?

Tags: phoenix-framework, surrealdb

We want to use surrealdb as our database but how would we use it in Phoenix? What configurations are needed? If you have any Experiences with this pls feel free to share :)

Answer (score 1):

I am working on SurrealDB library for Elixir. You can see how install and configure it on github: https://github.com/ricardombiot/surreal_ex

If you wants works with phoenix, you can create a project without ecto (using --no-ecto flags) and after includes library dependence and start your project!

For big projects/big-teams, I would recommend creates an umbrella project where you have your application will be divide on independent modules (E.g. A project for Web, other for REST, other for each service as users, mailing, booking.. so on…). The modular architecture improves testeability, reusability, extensibility of each part of your application.

Note: I had working on Library only one week (Nov 26, 2022) then consider that maybe some things can change on next versions.